# EF DbContext: inserted record to table (without SaveChanges()), why can't get it in query?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have code like this

```
        var context = new MyDbContext(); // db context generated from database

        var id = Guid.NewGuid();
        var cust = new customer()
        { Id = id, Name = "John" };

        context.Customers.Add(cust);

       // context.SaveChanges();

        var res = context.Customers.Where(c => c.Id == id);

        MessageBox.Show(res.Count().ToString());
```

I inserted a record to a table and when I am running a query I am expecting that result will contain this new record. But in fact it doesn't. It works only if I make SaveChanges() before.

What am I doing wrong, why it doesn't work that way?

Comment: The "context" is not a "cache".

Answer (score 6):

Try to query the local object

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696248(v=vs.103).aspx

```
context.Customers.Local.yourqueryhere
```

This will query entites tracked by the context, including these which are not yet saved.

Answer (score 3):

Because `var res = context.Customers.Where(c => c.Id == id);` reads from database.

`context.Customers.Add(cust);` adds the record in the context only (updating the object graph in EF's context) and `context.SaveChanges();` will save it to database.

Answer (score 0):

You did not insert the record. You just added it to the context on your local box. `.SaveChanges()` saves your local data to the database. Since queries always run against the database and you did not call `.SaveChanges()` your entity was not returned from the query.